# scrolling between invisible rects

Tags: ios, swift

Take a look at this picture :
[image]

Imagine a scroll view, where the pink rects are images each on a scroller page.

Imagine that the blue rects are **invisible** rects different in size on each page.

Imagine that the yellow rect is an image that is **static** = not on the scroll view.

I would like to scroll between 2 and 3, where the yellow stay at the same position, BUT it disappear when the blue rects moving. (you see it only inside)

In rect 3 you can see what happen to the yellow while scrolling .

How should I put my layers on the scroller to create such an effect ?

Comment: your description is confusing, so you want yellow to be static or move? just make blue one a scrollview, otherwise it will always will be in the center

Comment: Sorry. I also do not understand your suggestion. As I said yellow is looks like static, pink and blue are moving, but when they move, the yellow appears only when its inside the blue rect, so you don't see it between pages. it has bounds which are the blue rects.

Comment: so basically you want just scrolling pages with holes in the middle? did you start with any code?

Comment: its hard to describe it, sorry for the confusion, i am trying to make photos with "holes" in them, the holes are the blue rects, so the yellow appears only inside these blue windows.

Comment: I have a scrollview with photos, obviously, but am trying to figure what structure the views above it should have.

Comment: So basically the picture with the hole stays fixed, only the yellow box moves as you scroll?

Comment: No. the pink/blue moves. imagine that each page is a pink wall with a blue window, and when you scroll you see the sun from the window only, the sun looks static (its the yellow rect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on comments, it look like you need a scrollview with simple views. 
This views can be with overlay that has a hole inside, take a look at code for making layer with hole:

```
func layerWith(img: UIImage) -> CALayer {

    let overlay = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                           width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                                           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

    // Create the initial layer from the view bounds.
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = overlay.bounds
    let myImage = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage
    maskLayer.frame = myView.bounds
    maskLayer.contents = myImage

    // Create the frame.
    let radius: CGFloat = 150.0
    let rect = CGRect(x: overlay.frame.midX - radius,
                      y: overlay.frame.midY - radius,
                      width: 2 * radius,
                      height: 2 * radius)

    // Create the path.
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: overlay.bounds)
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    // Append the rect to the path so that it is subtracted.
    path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: rect))
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

    // Set the mask of the view.
    overlay.layer.mask = maskLayer

    // Add the view so it is visible.
    return overlay
}
```

And some code to add subviews into scrollview:

```
var i: CGFloat = 0
//or width that you want
let width = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.frame.width

for item in items {
     let frame = CGRect(x: width * i, y: 0, width: width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
     let v = UIView(frame: frame)
     //here you can add layer from code above to this view before adding it to scrollview
     v.layer.addSublayer(layerWith(img:your image goes here))
     self.scrollView.addSubview(v)

    i += 1
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I upvote, but I am not sure what you did, why is there black layer? and why is alpha is 0.85 ? I am not sure you understand the question ..

Comment: You have to see the pink photos, they are different, they can't be a constant black color, each pink rect is a different photo with a hole inside.

Comment: ok, soooo i thought you want to add something to cover photos inside, you want to have photos everywhere?, you can remove code with color, i even can do it for you

Comment: i have added a code for adding image layer, so if you will make a method that will just pass this image to creating layer and return layer you can make it work

Comment: So this image layer has a hole inside it ? If there will be an image behind it I will see only inside this rect path?

Comment: yes, if there will be image, it will be visible via cut layer part